# Ho do i change my component element size on a table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-components

i would like to know, how (and if there is) a possibility to resize a component imported in another page in Angular.

Here is what i have:

- I created a button component so that i could reuse it wherever i wanted (let's call it component A)
- I created a table on another component (let's call it component B).

---

Now if i import the component A on my table cell (situated in component B) i can not move it. I can't dynamically change his position. For reference i am using ng zorro table and in the `<td>` tag i put `nzAlign="center"` property. But it does not work the button is not being centered on the cell. As you can see here in the picture the `<app-delete-btn>` element has more width than the button itself and that is why is not getting centered. Thanks to whoever responds to this!

---

[Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY9lz.png)

Comment: try adding `text-align:center` to the `<td>` , since its using `display: table`

Comment: did you try to add "display: block" to your button ? In his own CSS, you can write `:host { display: block; }` ?

Comment: I fixed the error by setting ant button ```display: flex``` and ```margin: auto``` and ```align-items: center``` that way the button takes only the width needed therefore it works on my table. but thanks guys for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the error by changing the style of class `.ant-btn` in my `style.css`. so for class `.ant-btn`, add css properties `display: flex`, `margin: auto` and `align-items: center` that way the button takes only the width of itself therefore it works on table. But thanks guys for the tips!

```
.ant-btn{
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And then used `nzAlign` to align the button in the center on table.